# Change checkbox status by click but else not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

If I click into a div area and the checkbox is checked, if checked show clicked alert else unchecked is show unchecked alert. But else is not working.

```js
$("#hellofortest").on('click', function() {
  var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
  if (checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked"))) {
    alert("Check box in Checked");
  } else {
    alert("Check box is Unchecked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hellofortest">
  <div class="reg-header">
    <div class="reg-header-title">Title</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ceo-previous-data-checkbox">
    <div class="bx-item-field">
      <input type="checkbox" id="previous_info" name="previous_info" value="previous">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code work for me:

```
$("#hellofortest").on('click', function() {
  var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
  checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked"))
  if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
    alert("Check box in Checked");
  } else {
    alert("Check box is Unchecked");
  }
});
```

Another answer:

```
$(".markerDiv").click(function (e) {    
    if (!$(e.target).is('input:checkbox')) {
        var $checkbox = $(this).find('input:checkbox');
        $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));
    }
});
```

Thanks Both of you. Rory McCrossan And Ajith Gopi.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:checked` pseudo selector to check if a checkbox is checked. Use with with jQuery's `is` property like `checkbox.is(":checked")`

```js
$("#hellofortest").on('click', function() {
  var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
  if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
    alert("Check box in Checked");
  } else {
    alert("Check box is Unchecked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hellofortest">
  <div class="reg-header">
    <div class="reg-header-title">Title</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ceo-previous-data-checkbox">
    <div class="bx-item-field">
      <input type="checkbox" id="previous_info" name="previous_info" value="previous">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when click in #hellofortest area the check box will be work like check and uncheck.
And when checked by click #hellofortest  area   alert("Check box in Checked");
When again click it will be uncheck .and alert("Check box is Unchecked");
I am not find my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you're using the *setter* of `prop()` in your `if` condition. This always returns a jQuery object which coerces to a truthy value, hence the `else` is never fired.

To fix this, remove the second argument from `prop()`. Now that method call will return the boolean from the `checked` property on the checkbox.

```js
$("#hellofortest").on('click', function() {
  var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
  if (checkbox.prop("checked")) {
    console.log("Check box is Checked");
  } else {
    console.log("Check box is Unchecked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hellofortest">
  <div class="reg-header">
    <div class="reg-header-title">Title</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ceo-previous-data-checkbox">
    <div class="bx-item-field">
      <input type="checkbox" id="previous_info" name="previous_info" value="previous">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when click in #hellofortest area the check box will be work like check and uncheck.
And when checked by click #hellofortest  area   alert("Check box in Checked");
When again click it will be uncheck .and alert("Check box is Unchecked");
I am not find my answer.